# Java Sorting a Map using Steams VS TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Consider the following Java HashMap.

```
Map<String, String> unsortMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
unsortMap.put("Z", "z");
unsortMap.put("B", "b");
unsortMap.put("A", "a");
unsortMap.put("C", "c");
```

Now I wish to sort this Map by Key. One option is for me to use a TreeMap for this purpose.

```
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(unsortMap);
```

Another option is for me to Use Java Streams with Sorted(), as follows.

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();
unsortMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

Out of these two, which option is preferred and why (may be in terms of performance)?

Thank you

Comment: Your second option doesn't actually work. Surely that should count against it?

Comment: My understanding on HashMaps and LinkedHashMaps was low. I got it from this article, which actually has the correct implementation
https://howtodoinjava.com/sort/java-sort-map-by-key/

Comment: With the above comment, please do explain which option is much better? TreeMap of LinkedHashMap sorting via streams

Comment: Apples to oranges...they are not the same data structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by others dumping the sorted stream of entries into a regular `HashMap` would do nothing... `LinkedHashMap` is the logical choice.

However, an alternative to the approaches above is to make full use of the Stream `Collectors` API.

`Collectors` has a `toMap` method that allows you to provide an alternative implementation for the `Map`. So instead of a `HashMap` you can ask for a `LinkedHashMap` like so:

```
unsortedMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
       Map.Entry::getKey,
       Map.Entry::getValue,
       (v1, v2) -> v1, // you will never merge though ask keys are unique.
       LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Between using a TreeMap vs LinkedHashMap ... The complexity of construction is likely to be the same something like O(n log n)... Obviously the `TreeMap` solution is a better approach if you plan to keep adding more elements to it... I guess you should had started with a `TreeMap` in that case. The `LinkedHashMap` option has the advantage that lookup is going to be O(1) on the Linked or the original unsorted map whereas as TreeMap's is something like `O(log n)` so if you would need to keep the unsorted map around for efficient lookup whereas in if you build the LinkedHashMap you could toss the original unsorted map (thus saving some memory).

To make things a bit more efficient with `LinkedHashMap` you should provide an good estimator of the required size at construction so that there is not need for dynamic resizing, so instead of `LinkedHashMap::new` you say `() -> new LinkedHashMap<>(unsortedMap.size())`.

I'm my opinion the use of a `TreeMap` is more neat... as keeps the code smaller so unless there is actual performance issue that could be addressed using the unsorted and sorted linked map approach I would use the `Tree`.

Comment: Adding to this putting them in a hashmap would do nothing because it will simply insert the data in random order again.

Comment: @SanathKumar... not sure what you mean... the solution uses a ```LinkedHashMap``` not a regular ```HashMap```.

Comment: I was trying to explain why using a hashmap wouldn't work. It was meant for op not you.

Answer (score 1):

Your stream code won't even sort the map, because it is performing the operation against a `HashMap`, which is inherently unsorted.  To make your second stream example work, you may use `LinkedHashMap`, which maintains insertion order:

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
unsortMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

But now your two examples are not even the same underlying data structure.  A `TreeMap` is backed by a tree (red black if I recall correctly).  You would use a `TreeMap` if you wanted to be able to iterate in a sorted way, or search quickly for a key.  A `LinkedHashMap` is hashmap with a linked list running through it.  You would use this if you needed to maintain insertion order, for example when implementing a queue.

Answer (score 1):

The second way does not work, when you call `HashMap#put`, it does not hold the put order. You might need `LinkedHashMap`.

TreeMap v.s. Stream(LinkedHashMap):

1. code style. Using TreeMap is more cleaner since you can achieve it in one line.
2. space complexity. If the original map is `HashMap`, with both method you need to create a new `Map`. If If the original map is `LinkedHashMap`, then you only need create a new `Map` with the first approach. You can re-use the `LinkedHashMap` with the second approach.
3. time complexity. They should both have O(nln(n)).